# How to calculate what wattage transformer to use for LED light strip

Tags: electrical

I am looking to purchase some LED light strips, and I have seen these:

[7.5 Watt RGB LED Tape](http://www.instyleled.co.uk/75-watt-rgb-led-tape/)

They are 7.5w, and have 150 LED lights over a span of 5m and the website states that they are 12V. But I am not sure what transformer/driver to use for these lights. The QA section, below the product description mention:

*" To work out what transformer you require this is quite simple. You take the amount of LED tape you have in metres and x this by the wattage of the LED tape you have, again per metre.
For example 7m of 4.8w LED tape: 7 x 4.8w = 33.6w Therefore you would require a 60w transformer. "*

So for 5 meter of 7.5watts the calculation is 5 x 7.5 = 37.5W
The website has power transformers, but at 100W and 150W, and when I rang them they were out of stock and the prices for the transformers were about 3 times what I can see on ebay.

Firstly, **can I use a transformer that is producing 40W which is just above the 37.5W that I need, instead of a 150W transformer that they sell and claim is compatible for this LED strip**?

[Here is one transformer](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/141166740681), that looks equivalent to the one they sell, at a relatively affordable price:

This gives me 12v x 12.5A = 150W, but I can see a 15V x 10A, which also gives 150W. **Which of these is suitable for me (as they both produce the same wattage, but have different Volts/Amps), and what do the different Amps and Volts mean**?

Comment: If you have lights that are rated for 12 volts, you'll want to get a transformer/driver that outputs 12 volts.  It might be beneficial to do some research on [Volts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt), [Amperes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere),  [Watts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt), and [how they all interrelate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).

Comment: @Tester101, good call, thanks. I was just reading http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question501.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a 40w transformer to power your 37.5w load. However, given the quality of these small power supplies, running at 90%+ all the time will cause heat and premature failure probably.

You will need to drive the LEDs at 12v. Running them at 15-18v (or anything over 12!) is a bad idea for the life of the LED.  You will need to put a resistor on an 18v supply to bring it down.  I'd recommend simply getting the 150w 12v supply.  Wattage/amperage is different than volts, where you can use a higher powered power supply and the connected lights will only draw what they need (example: running a 12v 50w light bulb from a 12v power supply rated at 150w is fine. Running a 6v 50w bulb on the same power supply is not fine).

Comment: Is a 150W transformer not inefficient. I know the LEDs will draw however much they need, but would a 150W transformer not get a lot hotter than say a 60W transformer or a 40W transformer? If I get a 60W to be on the safe side (as my requirements are only for 37.5W load) - that would be a little bit more capacity than needed and less wasteful than 150W - am I right?

Comment: A power supply (PSU) will only draw as much power from the wall as it needs to power the load.  PSU's have a sweet spot for efficiency which could be in the 40-60% of rated load. So, if you need 75w, a 150w would be a good choice.  In your example, a 60w running 37w or a 150w running 37w will have a negligible difference of actual consumption.   Go for the 60.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have misread the listing for these lights. They are 7.5 watts for the whole string. These are incredibly bright and efficient lights that I have used for under-cabinet lighting and for accent lights. For the under cabinet lights, the sections are 1 - 2 meters long and only use a couple of hundred milliamps of power. I use the wall transformer power supplies designed for home CCTV cameras - 12v at 500 milliamps. They work great, they are small and can be hidden easily.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the same lights? the listing does specifically say under the specification tab: "7.2 Watts per metre" and later on says: "Reel length can be 5m or 10m"

Comment: I'm sorry but I did misread the description, but I still think their specs are not clear. This is the item that I have.http://www.tmart.com/20W-SMD5050-5m-150LEDs-White-Light-Epoxy-Waterproof-LED-Light-Strip-White-Lamp-Plate-12V_p171919.html As you can see it's only 20 watts for the whole strip. So calculating  for the 7.5 W per meter, it's 7.5 / 12v = .650 amps